# Problems loading google Maps API with requirejs

Tags: google-maps, requirejs

In my main.js file I have:

```
'use strict';

requirejs.config({

  baseUrl: './',

  paths: {
      'jquery': 'bower_components/jQuery/jquery.min',
      'async': 'bower_components/requirejs-plugins/src/async'
  }
});

require(['jquery', 'async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=siteKey'], function($, gMaps) {

  console.log("$=" + $); //defined and working
  console.log("gMaps=" + gMaps); //undefined

  });
```

It runs without errors and seems to load gMaps but the object is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this with this resource http://blog.millermedeiros.com/requirejs-2-0-delayed-module-evaluation-and-google-maps/

In main.js the code now is

```
requirejs.config({

    baseUrl: './',

    paths: {
        'jquery': 'bower_components/jQuery/jquery.min',
        'load': 'resources/js/index/load',
        'user': 'resources/js/index/user',
        'async': 'bower_components/requirejs-plugins/src/async'
       }
   });



require(['jquery', 'gMaps'], function($, gMaps) {

   console.log("$=" + $); //defined
   console.log('googleMaps=' + gMaps); // defined

   });


 define('gMaps', ['async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=siteKey'],
   function(){

      return window.google.maps;


     });


 define(['gMaps'], function(gMaps){

     console.log('googleMaps=' + gMaps); // defined

     });
```